# Using boolean values for lookup to create a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, comparison

I have a Dictionary and a list:

```
labels = {'cat_01.jpg': ['cat'], 'Poodle_07927.jpg': ['poodle'], 'duck_02.jpg': ['duck']}


mylist = ['cat 63663' ,'dog 4636773' ,'wolf 87487','croc 1331', 'bird 01']
```

mind that the `len()` of the dictionary is not equal to `mylist`

I'm looking at this:
If the value 'cat' from the dictionary in present in any of the elements of mylist say 'cat 63663'

I want that element to me appended to the value.
I'm looking for an output of the updated dictionary as:

```
label['cat_01.jpg'] = ['cat','cat 63663']
```

instead of

```
label['cat_01.jpg'] = ['cat']
```

I'm unable to iterate since the length of both iterables don't match.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it :

```
animal = [x.split('_')[0] for x in list(labels.keys())]
for element in mylist:
    current_animal = element.split(' ')[0]
    if current_animal in animal:
        labels[list(labels.keys())[animal.index(current_animal)]].append(element)
```

---

Using a for loop is faster than using a dictionary since you don't have to iterate through the animal list for each dictionary key. The update is done the other way around, here is a performance comparison :

For loop :

- 5.21 µs ± 20.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

@CristiFati dictionary comprehension :

- 965 ms ± 56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 1):

You could try a *dict comprehension*, which includes a (nested) *list comprehension* ([[Python 3.Docs]: Data Structures - Nested List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)). As a note, the syntax is quite complex, and the performance isn't the best.

> ```
> >>> labels = {'cat_01.jpg': ['cat'], 'Poodle_07927.jpg': ['poodle'], 'duck_02.jpg': ['duck']}
> >>> animal_list = ['cat 63663', 'dog 4636773', 'wolf 87487', 'croc 1331', 'bird 01']
> >>>
> >>> new_labels = {k: v + [item1 for item0 in v for item1 in animal_list if item0 in item1.split()] for k, v in labels.items()}
> >>>
> >>> new_labels
> {'cat_01.jpg': ['cat', 'cat 63663'], 'Poodle_07927.jpg': ['poodle'], 'duck_02.jpg': ['duck']}
> ```